# Parsing microseconds with boost

Tags: datetime, boost, milliseconds

I am looking for the `boost::posix_time::time_input_facet` that will let me parse milliseconds. It does not seem to be the same as the one for formatting microseconds which is `"%f"`

So if I have `2011-12-11 08:29:53.123000`, I would like to have the right formatting to parse it, something like that `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: *milli*seconds should be *micro*seconds

Comment: what is the goal? just to get the milliseconds/microseconds from a string in the above format or something else?

Comment: The aim is to have the ms/us information so that I can sort information according to their timestamps and then later display it back more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a date/time string you can convert that into a ptime object like this:

```
using boost::posix_time;
ptime t = time_from_string(datetimeString);
```

Having this you can easily get hold of the time_duration which holds the fractional seconds.

```
time_duration td = t.time_of_day();
long fs = td.fractional_seconds();
```

You can also get the total milliseconds or microseconds like this:

```
long ms = td.total_milliseconds();
long us = td.total_microseconds();
```

More information about what can be done in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

**UPDATE**

If the input format might be a different one, so you want to use the `time_input_facet` you can check the `time_facet.hpp` for appropriate format. Here is what you probably want to select from:

```
  static const char_type fractional_seconds_format[3];               // f                                                                                                                                 
  static const char_type fractional_seconds_or_none_format[3];       // F                                                                                                                                 
  static const char_type seconds_with_fractional_seconds_format[3];  // s
```

**UPDATE2**

In `time_facet.hpp` (Boost 1.45) I see the following when parsing:

```
case 'f':
{
    // check for decimal, check special_values if missing                                                                                                                                       
    if(*sitr == '.') {
        ++sitr;
        parse_frac_type(sitr, stream_end, frac);
        ...
```

I don't see why this would require anything but a dot between the seconds and the fractional seconds. Maybe you use another version of Boost?

Comment: It works indeed, but if I use a different formatting form my date, I am not sure it will still work. I am looking for the tag for milliseconds or microseconds to add to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. I thought it was `%3N` but it does not work

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s` works then. Also it's a bit weird because the parsing facet is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f`, but the formatting one is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` (note the `.` before `%f`)

Comment: Which version of boost are you using? In 1.45 I currently have I see the input facet checking for . (dot) before parsing fractional seconds.